# segmental k-means hmm algorithm

Tags: markov-chains

I'm trying to determine the state parameters for an hmm with a minimum of 9 states. I'm running chunks of my data through hmmtrain on MATLAB which I think uses the Baum/Welch aka forward/backward algorithm.  This tends to be very slow.  I have found several papers describing the segmental k-means algorithm for determining the hidden markov parameters.  However, none of the papers make clear where in the algorithm the segmentation and k-means clustering occurs (see Rabiner 1990).

Any insight into this algorithm would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I think if you asked this on cross validated,  you are far more likely to get an answer.  I have not personally heard of this algorithm.